# How is a BizTalk orchestration activated when it is not invoked by other orchestrations and has no inbound ports?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I need to review several BizTalk applications in the organization. I have found several enlisted orchestrations that apparently have no entry points and have no idea on how they operate, or how they are activated.

Comment: Using BizTalk 2010.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of Ports:

- The Orchestration is **Call**'ed or **Start**'ed using the **Call Orchestration Shape** or **Start Orchestration Shape**.  In that case, the called Orchestration has Parameters instead of an Activate Receive Shape.
- The Orchestration contains Types only and does not perform any actual work.  There would be no Shapes in this

Answer (score 0):

The orchestrations can activate with subscriptions directly to the MessageBox. If you configure in your orchestration with a **Direct Port**:

[image: Direct Port]

When you deploy this orchestration, **it hasn't any** Receive Port:

[image: Orchestration]

And you have to go to **BizTalk Administration > New > Query Expression** and search for **Suscriptions**. Then you see the properties that must complain a message to activate your orchestration:

[image: Subscription]